# error: no matching function for call to ... at return statement

Tags: c++, qt, initialization, return, explicit

I'm using GCC7 on Qt 5.9.4 on openSUSE Leap 15.

I have the following class:

```
class ManSuppProps : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ManSuppProps(QString parentName);
    explicit ManSuppProps(){}
    explicit ManSuppProps(const ManSuppProps &manSuppProps);
    explicit ManSuppProps(ManSuppProps &manSuppProps);
    ~ManSuppProps();

private:
    QVector3D m_suppPos;
    QString m_suppParentName;

}
```

With the following implementations for constructors:

```
ManSuppProps::ManSuppProps(QString parentName)
    : QObject()
    , m_suppPos(QVector3D(0, 0, 0))
    , m_suppParentName(parentName)
{
    qDebug()<<"Constructing ManSuppProps object ...";
}

ManSuppProps::ManSuppProps(const ManSuppProps &manSuppProps)
    : QObject()
    , m_suppPos(manSuppProps.getSuppPos())
    , m_suppParentName(manSuppProps.getSuppParentName())
{
}

ManSuppProps::ManSuppProps(ManSuppProps &manSuppProps)
    : QObject()
    , m_suppPos(manSuppProps.getSuppPos())
    , m_suppParentName(manSuppProps.getSuppParentName())
{

}

ManSuppProps::~ManSuppProps(){}
```

I'm receiving the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘ManSuppProps::ManSuppProps(ManSuppProps&)’

At a method of another class which has a member of class `ManSuppProps`:

```
ManSuppProps EditorScene::manSuppProps()
{
    return m_manSuppProps; // error is thrown here
}
```

Considering I have all the constructors, I don't get why the error is received. Can anybody help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Note that the appropriate constructor is declared as `explicit` as

```
explicit ManSuppProps(ManSuppProps &manSuppProps);
```

And `return m_manSuppProps;` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization),

> 4) when returning from a function that returns by value

And copy-initialization doesn't consider `explicit` constructors.

(emphasis mine)

> If `T` is a class type and the cv-unqualified version of the type of `other` is `T` or a class derived from `T`, **the non-explicit constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution**. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.
>
> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: **explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization**.

Comment: … and that's why I never make copy and move c'tors `explicit`, even if all other c'tors are.

Comment: fwiw, the [C++ Core Guidelines agree](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-explicit) not to declare copy/move constructors as `explicit` for the same reason: "_**Note**

Copy and move constructors should not be made `explicit` because they do not perform conversions. Explicit copy/move constructors make passing and returning by value difficult._"